# Debug current instruction pointer [eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm having this little task to create an gui with a field and a button. Nothing hard but i can't run the programm. Eclipse keep telling me to debug current instruction pointer at line 18 "public static void main.."

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel panou;

    private JButton schimba;

    private JTextField field;

    public Test(String _z) {
        super(_z);
        initComponents();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] _args){
        Test _frame = new Test("andreiterecoasa");
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panou = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        schimba = new JButton("Schimba");
        field = new JTextField(30);

        panou.add(schimba);
        panou.add(field);
        add(panou);

        schimba.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String a = field.getText();
                Cuvant z = new Cuvant(a);
                field.setText(z.intoarce());
            }
        });
    }




}
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace also

Comment: Guess you have marked a debug instruction pointer, look left from the line-begins and you might see a dot, double clicking on it removes it. (yep it's in line 18)

Comment: How are you trying to run your program? Aren't you debugging accidentally? Any breakpoints defined?

Comment: via eclipse and via cmd!

Comment: Also: public static void main(String[] args) { has to be exactly like I wrote it, remove the _ .

Comment: Please describe the commands / Eclipse controls that you are using to run the program.

Comment: In eclipse -> F11

In cmd java Test

Comment: In cmd when running i get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: unresolved compilation problem: at test.main.."

Comment: Works for me your script, although I had to import a bit more things because of the ActionListener.

Comment: Oh snap. that gave me an idea. it seem that if i import thing separately not the entire class..it works!

Comment: Anyway. Thanks. wish i could give you a reward!:D

Comment: You were importing an entire PACKAGE (and that is still not true; you only import the classes you actually use from said package), and you were simply missing one.